# I have ball pen marks in page 2 of my passport. Is it considered damaged?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-stamps, passport-renewals, damaged-passports

My passport has three small blue ball pen marks
Is it considered damaged?

[image]

Comment: I have a mark in my passport that is only slightly less conspicuous than that.  No border officer has noticed so far.  It's unlikely that an officer would think that this mark makes the passport invalid, I would say very unlikely, but it's not impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply 